# Banking System Program

Tags: visual-c++

I've slowly been building up my banking system and need help. First though a quick run through. 1. choose an existing account or new one. 2. after that it will display the options of withdraw, deposit or close account (close account is the least of my worries as of right now). I've been using two different text documents as well. One is "Accounts" where it will scan or add accounts the other is "Money" where it should keep track of money in each account. The question is how can I assign the money to each account?

I've head of struct arrays, however it is confusing me. If that is the best course of action I'm going to need a mini walkthrough by making comments on the coding for me to better understand it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>//used to move text 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int display(char& anwser);

void N_account(char& anwser, string& name);

int Exist(string& name_search, char& anwser, string name_from_file, char& 
anwser2, string& money_deposit);

void deposit(string& money_deposit, char& anwser, char& anwser2, int& money_D);

void withdraw(string& withdraw_money, char& anwser, char& anwser2, int& money_D, string& total_money, int& money_W);


int main()
{

        int start_money, money_D, money_W;

    string name, name_search, name_from_file, money_deposit, withdraw_money, total_money;

    char anwser, anwser2;

    display(anwser);

    if (anwser == '1')
    {
        N_account(anwser, name);
    }

    if (anwser == '2')
    {
        Exist(name_search, anwser, name_from_file, anwser2, money_deposit);
    }

    if (anwser2 == '1')
    {
        deposit(money_deposit, anwser, anwser2, money_D);
    }

    if (anwser2 == '2')
    {
        withdraw(withdraw_money, anwser, anwser2, money_D, total_money, money_W);
    }

}

int display(char& anwser)
{

    cout << setw(65) << "=================" << endl;
    cout << setw(65) << "Banking Managment" << endl;
    cout << setw(65) << "=================" << endl;
    cout << setw(60) << "1.New account" << endl;
    cout << setw(65) << "2.Existing account" << endl;
    cin >> anwser;
    return 0;
}

void N_account(char& anwser, string& name)
{

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Accounts.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    cout << "Enter in first and last name for new account:";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, name);
    outfile << name;
    outfile << endl;
    cout << "Account added" << endl;
    outfile.close();


}

int Exist(string & name_search, char& anwser, string name_from_file, char& anwser2, string & money_deposit)

{

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("Accounts.txt");

    cout << "Enter in your account:";

    cin.ignore();

    getline(cin, name_search);

    while (getline(infile, name_from_file))
    {
        if (name_from_file == name_search)
        {
            cout << "Account found: " << name_search << endl;
            cout << "Choose what you would like to do" << endl;
            cout << setw(56) << "1.Deposit" << endl;
            cout << setw(57) << "2.Withdraw" << endl;
            cout << setw(62) << "3.Close account" << endl;
            cin >> anwser2;
            return 0;
        }

    }
    infile.close();

}

void deposit(string & money_deposit, char& anwser, char& anwser2, int& money_D)
{

    ofstream O_file;
    O_file.open("Money.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    cout << "Enter in how much you would like to deposit: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, money_deposit);
    money_D = stoi(money_deposit);//converts string into integer so that I may use basic operators such as less than or subtraction ect.
    if (money_D < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    O_file << money_deposit;
    O_file << endl;
    O_file.close();

}

void withdraw(string & withdraw_money, char& anwser, char& anwser2, int& money_D, string & total_money, int& money_W)
{

    ofstream O_file;
    O_file.open("Money.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    cout << "Enter in how much you would like to withdraw:";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, withdraw_money);
    money_W = stoi(withdraw_money);//converting string to integer
    total_money = money_W - money_D;
    O_file << total_money;
    O_file << endl;
    O_file.close();

}
```

When I choose the account named "John Doe" with a balance of $45.00 and wish to withdraw $20.00 I want the money for John Doe to decrease to $25.00 and NOT make a new line in the "Money" text document saying $20.00 like it has been doing.

The existing accounts are:

John Doe

Jane Doe

Travis Scott

William Smith

Patrick Michaels

Courtney Desmond

Their bank accounts are:

45.00

98.00

48.00

56.00

120.00`